# lodash - convert an object into a sorted array based on the keys of the object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to use lodash to convert an object like this:

```
var a = {1:'a', 3:'b', 2:'c'};
```

into a sorted array of values based on the keys of the object like:

```
var result = ['a','c','b'];
```

I know I can do this:

```
var keyRef = Object.keys(a).sort();
var result = keyRef.map(v => a[v]);
```

But is this way optimized - is there any function in lodash which is more optimized for this??

Answer (score 4):

With plain Javascript, you could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and take this array as sorted result, because if the keys of the object could be read as 32 bit integer numbers, Javascript use them in numerical order.

Source:

- [The traversal order of object properties in ES6](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html)

```js
var object = { 1: 'a', 3: 'b', 2: 'c' },
    values = Object.values(object);
    
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash,

```js
const o = {1:'a', 3:'b', 2:'c'};
const res = _.sortBy(o, (a, b) => b);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash has the [`_.values(obj)`](https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#values) function. However it is noted that the result ordering is not guaranteed. However, as @Nina pointed out, if you stick to ints as the keys, the ordering should be consistent (unless lodash is doing something weird).